# css without create each border color set top / bottom / left / right to fill the color

Tags: html, css

**css**

```
.callout {
    background-color: inherit;
    border: 1px solid #eee;
}
.callout.top {
    border-top-width: .25rem;
}
.callout.bottom {
    border-bottom-width: .25rem;
}
.callout.left {
    border-left-width: .25rem;
}
.callout.right {
    border-right-width: .25rem;
}
.primary {
    border-color: #428bca;
}
```

**html**

```
<div class="callout left primary">
    whole border is primary color
</div>
```

How to set left border is primary color only, and others are #eee color

Edit: added a image, i want look like this

[image]

and just in case need to overwrite the border color with the use

```
<div class="callout top primary border-warning">
    same problem as above
</div>
```

Comment: did you google ? took me 2 seconds https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-right-color

Comment: @noa-dev sorry, i don't understand, this is something like dynamic border color, because the .primary class does not know which side to replace the color, it is depends on the top / bottom / left / right

Answer (score 0):

Through this [link](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_border-left_color.asp), each border position (`left`, `right`, `top`, `bottom`) has got specific `color`, `width`, `style` css attributes.

```css
.callout {
    background-color: inherit;
    border: 1px solid #eee;
}
.callout.top {
    border-top-width: .25rem;
    border-top-color: #428bca;
}
.callout.bottom {
    border-bottom-width: .25rem;
    border-bottom-color: #428bca;
}
.callout.left {
    border-left-width: .25rem;
    border-left-color: #428bca;
}
.callout.right {
    border-right-width: .25rem;
    border-right-color: #428bca;
}
.primary {
    border-color: #428bca;
}
```

```html
<div class="callout left">
    whole border is primary color
</div>
<br>
<div class="callout top border-warning">
    same problem as above
</div>
```

Comment: this can't solve the problem, i want ONLY top / bottom / left / right with primary only, other three keep the border-color #eee, so hardcored 'border-top-color: #428bca;' in top/bottom/left/right is not good, because top/bottom/left/right is base on .primary color

Answer (score 0):

ok i googled is able use variables in css [Using CSS custom properties (variables)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties)

so to avoid add each color set top / bottom / left / right

the finally code just like this

**css**

```
.callout {
    background-color: inherit;
    border: 1px solid #eee;
}
.callout.top {
    border-top-width: .27rem;
    border-top-color: var(--callout-border-color, inherit);
}
.callout.bottom {
    border-bottom-width: .27rem;
    border-bottom-color: var(--callout-border-color, inherit);
}
.callout.left {
    border-left-width: .27rem;
    border-left-color: var(--callout-border-color, inherit);
}
.callout.right {
    border-right-width: .27rem;
    border-right-color: var(--callout-border-color, inherit);
}
.callout.primary {
    --callout-border-color: #428bca;
}
.callout.warning {
    --callout-border-color: #f0ad4e;
}
.callout.danger {
    --callout-border-color: #d9534f;
}
```

**html**

```
<div class="callout top primary">top</div>

<div class="callout left warning">left</div>

<div class="callout right danger">right</div>
```

**result**

[image]

so if i want add a new color, just add

```
.callout.success {
    --callout-border-color: #5cb85c;
}
```

no need to add any more top / bottom / left / right class

or any better solution ??